# Overlaypanel inside picklist inside dialog not showing value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, editor, overlay

I have this button in a form

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" update=":solution" title="Modify"
 actionListener="#{controller.addSolutionAction(registerCause)}"
 icon="ui-icon-plus" />
```

It displays this dialog (it's outside the form)

```
<p:dialog header="Solutions widgetVar="dlgSolution" id="solution"
 showEffect="fade" hideEffect="drop" closable="true" resizable="true" modal="true">
    <h:form id="dialog">
         <p:pickList id="solutions" var="sol" effect="drop" 
          itemValue="#{sol}" itemLabel="#{sol.code}" converter="solutionConverter" label="Solutions" >
          <f:facet name="sourceCaption">No Seleccionadas</f:facet>
          <f:facet name="targetCaption">Seleccionadas</f:facet>
          <p:ajax event="transfer" update="@form"
          listener="#{controller.handleSolutionChange}" />
          <p:column>  
             <h:outputText id="codeID" value="#{sol.code}" /> 
          </p:column>
          <p:column>
             <p:commandButton id="button" icon="ui-icon-search" type="button" update="buttonP"/>
                <p:overlayPanel id="buttonP" for="button" hideEffect="fade">
                     <p:editor id="description" required="true" 
                       label="Ver más" width="300" widgetVar="descriptionWidget" 
                       value="#{sol.description}"  disabled="true" controls="">
                     </p:editor>
                </p:overlayPanel>
          </p:column>
         </p:pickList>  

         <p:outputPanel styleClass="divButton">
         <p:growl id="growlMessagePreview" life="2000" />

          <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="Close" process="@form" update="@form" value="Close" oncomplete="dlgSolution.hide()" />
         </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

What I want to do is show the solution's description when I click the button, but it's always empty. I need it to be an editor because the text is formatted
(I tried using a text area but it's empty too), then I put a string but it's not shown. I also used `dynamic = "true"` in the overlaypanel, it showed the hard coded string but not the value I need.

I'm using Primefaces 3.5. Any suggestions will be welcome, if you need more details, let me know.

Comment: `p:dialog header="Solutions widgetVar` - a closing quote is missing.

Comment: What are those `p:column`'s doing here? They don't belong in a form. Also you shouldn't update the dialog itself, you should its contents - `update=":solution:dialog"`.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov about the dialog header, it was a typo. It's fine in my code. About the columns, they're inside a picklist not just the form and I'm updating just the dialog so it shows up, data is loaded in the method `addSolutionAction` so everything needed it's there before the dialog shows. I still tried your suggestion and it throws and error `SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: solution`